# Running python setup.py install before each run in eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, windows, pydev

I've recently switched to windows to develop a python project, and my setup is using eclipse w/ pydev. I would like to execute "python setup.py install" before I run any scripts within my project. My question is: is it possible to have a pre-processing step do "python setup.py install" before I run any script in my project? (I would like to make it so I can just click the green run arrow and it will do the pre-processing and then run the current file).

Thanks!

Couldn't find an answer to this from doing a few google and stack overflow searches, if there is a duplicate, please link.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one helps you:

```
import os

string = "python setup.py install"
os.system(string)
```

Comment: thanks, yeah I could do this before each script, but I was hoping to find a more general solution, especially because sometimes the scripts are in a nested directory below the directory containing the setup.py file